# Concatenating an xPath query in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

I'm using xPath to query a HTML document. I'm setting a string as the contents of the xPath query. So in this case '$category_titles' is set to the the text that the query returns.

```
$category_titles = $xpath->query('//*[@id="test"]/div/div/h1');
```

Is there a way to pass in the values of two xpath queries in to my string though? So effectively, I need to set $category_titles to the result of two separate xPath values.

Comment: could you provide an example, what you would expect to have at the end? it's kind of hard to follow

Comment: Pass it to 2 temp variables and concat them?? into your $category_titles??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use operator | to merge more than one different paths into one.
this is valid:

```
$titles = $xpath->query('//*[@id="test"]/div/div/h1 | //*[@id="test1"]/div/div/h1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you want exactly, but if you are trying to have two xpath results in the same variable, the only way is using a `array`.

```
$category_title = array();
$category_titles[0] = $xpath->query('//*[@id="test"]/div/div/h1');
$category_titles[1] = $xpath->query('//*[@id="test1"]/div/div/h1');//I changed the ID, but you can change your entire query
```

Then, if you want to concatenate it, just a `$concat = "$category_titles[0]" . "$category_titles[1]"` is enough.

However, if you are trying create a second query using the result of first one and then concatenate, you can do:

```
$category_titles = $xpath->query('//*[@id="test"]/div/div/h1');
$category_titles = "$category_titles" . $xpath->query("//*[@id=\"$category_titles\"]/div/div/h1");// Note the escaped slashes
```